# How to make GNOME 3 use suspend-hybrid?

Tags: linux, gnome, hibernate, gnome3, suspend

How can I make GNOME 3 use `pm-suspend-hybrid` instead of `pm-suspend` when closing the lid or using suspend from the menu?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is pm-suspend-hybrid support but you can use this to change the lid close action to hiberate `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action "hibernate"` and `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action "hibernate"`  you can also use "blank" or "shutdown" as the action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Be sure it works

First of all you need to be sure `pm-suspend-hybrid` works on your computer. Type

```
sudo pm-suspend-hybrid
```

in console and notice if it works as expected.

### Hacking

It is more the hack than a solution. But it works for me.

Execute the following commands in the console:

```
ls -l /usr/sbin/pm-suspend  # it should be symlink to /usr/lib/pm-utils/bin/pm-action
sudo rm /usr/sbin/pm-suspend  # just remove this link
sudo editor /usr/sbin/pm-suspend  # create new file instead of symlink
```

Contents of the **new `pm-suspend` script**:

```
#!/bin/bash
pm-suspend-hybrid
# notice that you need to execute "pm-suspend-hybrid"
# just changing symlink is not enough
```

Than give execution rights to this new script:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

*Enjoy!*

---

#### Notes

- If your distribution does not use `sudo` command you need to be root to execute these commands.
- It is possible that `pm-suspend` is located at another path on your system. Just type `whereis pm-suspend` to find correct path.
- You may use any text editor of your choice instead of `editor` if you want or if your distribution does not have this wrapper.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! I had the same idea a while ago but didn't bother trying it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a workflow without having to create a file, without deleting the original file and that works in one command. Paste this in a terminal if you already know that your machine support hybrid suspension:

```
sudo mv /usr/sbin/pm-suspend /usr/sbin/pm-suspend_traditional && sudo ln -sf /usr/sbin/pm-suspend-hybrid /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

With the command above you will be enabling the hybrid suspension by default on your system. It is totally safe. Restoring The original config can restored by entering this command:

```
sudo mv /usr/sbin/pm-suspend_traditional /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

---

#### Step by step explanation

First you should check if your machine support H-S.

1. check if HS is supported by pasting this in a terminal (source webupd8 http://goo.gl/kjISbj):

   ```
   sudo pm-is-supported --suspend-hybrid && echo "hybrid suspend is supported" || echo "your system doesn't support hybrid suspend"
   ```

   The output of this command is a message that says if your machine does support or not hybrid-suspension.
2. Make a backup

   sudo mv /usr/sbin/pm-suspend /usr/sbin/pm-suspend_traditional
3. Make a link instead of a script:

   ```
   sudo ln -sf /usr/sbin/pm-suspend-hybrid /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
   ```

That's it.

Note: *The re-hack just combines steps 2 and 3.*

The advantages of this method compared with Lig's one are:

1. avoid the need to (and you shouldn't) delete the original `pm-suspend` file
2. it creates a backup that allows you to restore the previous setting
3. avoid the need of editing a new file, instead just link the original existent one with a symbolic link (`ln -s`).

Comment: Please note: Answers can be sorted in a number of ways, so "the response above" really doesn't have any context here.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed, that's why I put the author's name. What would be the proper way to cite it?

Comment: The author name is okay. Not so useful when there's a lot of answers, though, so I would link to the answer referenced.

Comment: Does not works, as @lig says, it is required that the script is called with the right name (*pm-suspend-hybrid*) so that the rigth action is performed. symlink is not enough.